# Parse XML ampersand in Java

Tags: java, php, xml

I download an XML-file, I generate using PHP, that looks similar to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<customersXML> 
   ...
   <customer id="12" name="Me+%26+My+Brother" swid="1" /> 
   ...
</customersXML>
```

Now I need to parse it in Java, but before that I use URL-Decode, so the XML become this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<customersXML> 
   ...
   <customer id="12" name="Me & My Brother" swid="1" /> 
   ...
</customersXML>
```

But when I parse the XML-file using SAX, I get a problem with "&". How can I get around this?

Comment: Why URL-encode in the first place something that's not a URL?

Comment: I URL-Encode it because I thought, it will help

Comment: Oh, well, then you can also `addslashes()` and `base64_encode()` as well ;-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ampersand is a special character in xml ([O'reilly Xml: Entities: Handling Special Content](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/01/31/qanda.html)) and needs to be encoded. Replace it with `&amp;` before sending it.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was something like that ;) 
Now I just need to create some replaces or something similar

Comment: No, you need to encode it as `&amp;` in the original XML, instead of URL-encoding anything.

Answer (score 2):

If the XML in question isn't urlencoded in the first place (which it doesn't look like it is), then you shouldn't be urldecoding it. Breaking the xml and then "unbreaking" it really doesn't seem like the best way to go about it. Just use the original xml and parse that.

Answer (score 2):

Never process XML as a string without parsing it, or you are liable to end up with something that is no longer XML. As you have discovered.

Answer (score 0):

You should FIRST parse, THEN url decode.